# Cleaner methods of jquery .click and .css

Tags: jquery, css

JQuery is not my number 1 language so I do whats necessary to get the job done. However, I have created a monster and wondering if theres a much cleaner method to do the following:

I have a series of divs that look like the following:

```
<div class="competency_keys key_1" title="" id="tog1"></div>
<div class="competency_keys key_2" title="" id="tog2"></div>
<div class="competency_keys key_3" title="" id="tog3"></div>
```

The ID's run from tog1 - tog8 and when you click on one it alters the css of the rest, like the following:

```
$("#tog1").click(function(){
    $(".overall").fadeIn().css("display", "block");
    $(".score1").css("display", "none");
    $(".score2").css("display", "none");
    $(".score3").css("display", "none");
    $(".score4").css("display", "none");
    $(".score5").css("display", "none");
    $(".score6").css("display", "none");  
    $(".score7").css("display", "none");
    $(".score8").css("display", "none");    
    $(".score9").css("display", "none"); 
    $(".key_1").css("opacity", "1");
    $(".key_2").css("opacity", "0.2");
    $(".key_3").css("opacity", "0.2");
    $(".key_4").css("opacity", "0.2");
    $(".key_5").css("opacity", "0.2");
    $(".key_6").css("opacity", "0.2");
    $(".key_7").css("opacity", "0.2");
    $(".key_8").css("opacity", "0.2");
    $(".key_9").css("opacity", "0.2");
    document.getElementById('ocsTitle').innerHTML = 'Overall Competency Score';
});
```

I have 8 of those codeblocks - it does work but its a hell of a lot of code. There must be a much cleaner solution?

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You should use CSS classes instead.

Comment: @SLaks Could you show me a very simple version so I can compare?

Comment: You can also chain selectors in jQuery with commas like so: `$(".score1, .score2, .score3").css("display", "none")`. [See the documentation here.](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

Comment: @nicholas79171 i might use the chain method for now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not entirely sure I understand what you are trying to do, but if you are trying to change opacity of every other div except the one you clicked on, you could go about it like this:

```
<div id="clicker"> <!--Add another div outside-->
    <div class="competency_keys key_1" title="" id="tog1"></div>
    <div class="competency_keys key_2" title="" id="tog2"></div>
    <div class="competency_keys key_3" title="" id="tog3"></div>
    <!--And so forth-->
</div>
<script>
$('#clicker').children().click(function() {
    $(this).css("opacity", "1")
    $(this).siblings().css("opacity", "0.2");
});
</script>
```

If you are going to remove all scores, give them a common class (or use a for loop, if that's not possible). You can keep rest of the code as it is. You don't need 8 blocks.

Answer (score 2):

Here are 2 of the many ways you could go about this:

### Chaining Selectors

Like I mentioned in your comment, you can [chain selectors in jQuery.](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) Your code might look like:

```
$("#tog1").click(function(){
    $(".overall").fadeIn().css("display", "block");
    $(".score1", ".score2", ".score3", ".score4", ".score5", ".score6", ".score7", ".score8", ".score9").hide();
    $(".key_1").css("opacity", "1");
    $(".key_2", ".key_3", ".key_4", ".key_5", ".key_6", ".key_7", ".key_8", ".key_9").css("opacity", "0.2");
    document.getElementById('ocsTitle').innerHTML = 'Overall Competency Score';
});
```

This is still kinda messy and doesn't leverage CSS and classes very well. (By the way, `.hide()` is the same thing as `.css("display", "none")` in jQuery).

### Using Classes

The better way to do this is to leverage classes. You'd have to add a class or two to your elements, but it'd be much cleaner. Your code, for example, could look like:

```
$("#tog1").click(function(){
    $(".overall").fadeIn().css("display", "block");
    $(".score").hide();
    $(".key_1").css("opacity", "1");
    $(".competency_keys").css("opacity", "0.2");
    document.getElementById('ocsTitle').innerHTML = 'Overall Competency Score';
});
```

It looks like you're confusing classes with IDs. Classes apply to multiple elements while IDs apply to single elements. Since you have a bunch of "score" elements and a bunch of "key" elements that are going to behave relatively the same way, they should be grouped together with classes. More info on class vs ID can be found [here.](https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/)

Answer (score 1):

You can fade all of them, and then just show the one you clicked.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".competency_keys").click(function(){

     $(".competency_keys").css('opacity',0.2);
     $(this).css('opacity',1);

     $(".overall").fadeIn().css("display", "block");
     for (var a=1; a<9; a++) {
         $(".score"+a).css("display", "none");
     }
     //document.getElementById('ocsTitle').innerHTML = 'Overall Competency Score';

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="competency_keys key_1" title="" id="tog1">A</div>
<div class="competency_keys key_2" title="" id="tog2">B</div>
<div class="competency_keys key_3" title="" id="tog3">C</div>
```

Try running the above and clicking any of the letters to see the effect.

Please note I had to comment out part of the JavaScript so it wouldn't throw errors in the snippet.

Answer (score 1):

CSS has attribute selectors so you can do something like:

```
div[class^="score"]{
    display: none;
}
```

Selects the class that starts with `score`. You can do the same with `key_`

Answer (score 0):

You could add another class to .score1-9 and .key_1-9

```
<span class="hideme score1"></span>
<span class="opaceme key_1"></span>
```

`$(".hideme").css("display", "none");` would hide all of the elements with that class

`$(".opaceme").css("opacity", "0.2");` would apply your opacity to all elements with this class

Seems like key_1 is a little different on the opacity. But this would simplify your code

I think this is what user Slacks was getting at in the comment section of the question.